# Diophantine equation for Multivariate Polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations

Here $a(t,M)$, $b(t,M)$, $c(t,M)$, $x(t,M)$, and $y(t,M)$ are Laurent polynomials in $t$ and $M$ with rational coefficients.

> I am given $a(t,M)$, $b(t,M)$, and $c(t,M)$. Is there a way for me to tell if a solution in $x(t,M)$ and $y(t,M)$ there exists for the following equation
>   $$a(t,M)x(t,M)+b(t,M)y(t,M)=c(t,M).$$

If this solution exist, can I say that $\gcd(a(t,M),b(t,M))$ divides $c(t,M)$?

Comment: Can you solve this problem for integers?

Comment: @saulspatz I believe for integers, $ax+by=c$ if and only if $gcd(a,b)$ divides c.

Comment: I think i can use the following: Let $G = \{g_t, \cdots, g_t\}$ be a Groebner basis for an ideal $I \subset k[x_1, . . . , x_n]$ and let $f \in k[x_1, . . . , x_n].$ Then $f \in I$ if and only if the remainder on division of $f$ by $G$ is zero.

Comment: I meant to say that for integers, it's just the Euclidean algorithm, so if Laurent polynomials in two variables form a Euclidean ring, you should be able to use the same proof.  I didn't say what I meant, sorry.  Now that I think about it, the ring of polynomials over a field in two variables is not a PID, much less a Euclidean ring, so my idea is probably a nonstarter.  So, what does $gcd$ mean in this domain?

Comment: @saulspatz it makes sense to talk about $gcd$ in any integral domain, although it may not exist. The most general rings on which it always exists are UFDs, and here you can obtain it just by looking at the factorization

Comment: @Pedro Been too many years (decades) since I took algebra

Answer (score 1):

If such a solution exists, then it is a multiple of the greatest common divisor (because a sum of multiples of an element is a multiple of that element).

For your first question, I believe you are looking for something such as Bézout's identity: if we were in a Bézout domain, we could say that such a solution exists if the RHS is a multiple of the greatest common divisor.

But I don't think your ring is a Bézout domain. The ring $\mathbb{Q}[t]$ is a PID, and so is its localization $R=\mathbb{Q}[t,t^{-1}]$. Hence $R$ is a Bézout domain. But now, $R[M]$ is not a PID any more, neither is its localization $S=R[M,M^{-1}]$. To show now that your ring $S$ is not a Bézout domain, try to argue like you would in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$: the $gcd$ of $x$ and $y$ is $1$, but $1\notin (x,y)$.